# How to use onboard wifi on Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: wireless, server, 16.04, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I need to run Ubuntu on it. I put the 16.04 server image for the Raspberry Pi 3 from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi on a microSD card and it boots fine, and works fine when connected to Ethernet.

However, I cannot seem to get the onboard wifi working with Ubuntu 16.04. Wireless works fine with Raspbian so I know the hardware is OK.

Has anyone got the on board WiFi working with Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3? I feel like it's really close to working, but I just am missing some small detail.

After a fresh install, `sudo lshw -C network` does show `wlan0`, although I can't find that defined anywhere in `/etc/network`, and it's initially disabled.

I then installed `wpasupplicant` and added this to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And put this in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US
network={
        ssid="homewifi"
        psk="xxx"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
network={
        ssid="phonewifi"
        psk="xxx"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

To get those settings, I booted Raspbian, connected to those two different SSIDs, and just copied the settings to Ubuntu. However after a reboot, `wlan0` does not connect to either network, never gets an IP, etc.

Is wpa-supplicant just not the way to configure WiFi for the Raspberry Pi 3 using Ubuntu Server 16.04? Or am I configuring something incorrectly?

Answer (score 8):

**For the image with apt installed**

> ```
> OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS  OS 
> image: ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img
> HW: RASPBERRY PI 3 MODEL B
> ```
>
> **Step1:**
>
> > `sudo apt-get install wireless-tools`
>
> **Step2:**
>
> > `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`
>
> **Step3:** add to `/etc/network/interfaces`:
>
> ```
> auto wlan0 
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp
> wpa-ssid WIRELESSSSID 
> wpa-psk WIRELESSPASSWORD
> ```
>
> **Step4:** comment from `/etc/network/interfaces` the line:
>
> ```
> #source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
> ```
>
> the commented `interfaces.d/*.cfg` file contains settings for the
>   eth0.
>
> I do not understand why but leaving this line active and adding the
>   wlan0 config would crash the system at boot.
>
> **Step5:** reboot

**For the core image without apt installed:**

> ```
> OS: Ubuntu Core 16 
> image: (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1030-raspi2 armv7l)
> HW: RASPBERRY PI 3 MODEL B
> ```
>
> **Step1:**
>
> ```
> ifconfig wlan0 down
> ifconfig wlan0 up
> ```
>
> **Step2:** create wireless config file:
>
> ```
> sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
> ```
>
> Note: I tried without sudo but it would not let me save the changes
>
> **Step3:** add the following content
>
> ```
> auto wlan0 
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp
> wpa-ssid WIRELESSSSID 
> wpa-psk WIRELESSPASSWORD
> ```
>
> **Step4:** reboot

Comment: how did you make that if apt is not present yet? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover ubuntu core also

Comment: isn't that a typo. essid should just be ssid?

Comment: Using blockquotes formatting indicates that the text is not yours. Is that the case? If so, citing the source would be nice.

Comment: Why isn't these packages pre-installed in the image?  People have to use ethernet to get WiFi working, it's really a joke.

Comment: if question is about connecting to wifi then how its supposed to download package without wifi/network. For even ifconfig not working as its needed to be installed first. So im just stucked.

Comment: @Rajendra You can use Option 1: a wired connection to install and download the required package. Option 2: create a temporary unprotected wireless connection, install wpasupplicant then do the required setup and switch the the protected connection.

Answer (score 3):

This is my config (slightly different to the others as I use wpa_supplicant.conf)

In /etc/network/interfaces I have:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

where the file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf contains the following:

```
country=GB

network={
    ssid="MyWifiNetwork"
    psk="myP4ssw0rd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is the solution that looks most like the Raspbian docs. Clean!

Answer (score 1):

I did iwconfig command and from there the messages came that dependicies needed to be updated and after that I could install the wireless-tools.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -f install wireless-tools
```

after these commands I was able to iwconfig.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Any success so far? Did you read this?
[ubuntu WPAHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WPAHowTo)

Accordingly, I installed this on my RPi3 running ubuntu MATE 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install wpagui
```

Where it tells one to be run like this:
You will need to run it via gksudo wpa_gui so that it can talk to the WPA daemon.

```
gksudo wpa_gui
```

Even if it may not be available on your server version, due to a missing GUI(?), it may be helpful for testing purposes on the Raspbian OS. Or even assist in deducting correct settings. Which it did in my case.

Comment: wpa-supplicant and wpa_gui were developed alongside.So yes, wpa-supplicant is the way to configure WiFi for the Raspberry Pi 3. wpa_gui just offers a GUI for it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe my solution duplicate to someone else. Anyway try just follow these 3 steps.

Install WPA Supplicant

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as below. Edit `Your Wifi Name`(support space) and `yourPassword` according your preferences.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
# source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The wireless network interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid My Wifi Name
wpa-psk yourPassword

# The primary network interface
# allow-hotplug eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Reboot your system

```
sudo reboot
```

This solution work for both *raspberry pi 3 and 2* & *Ubuntu Server 14.04 and 16.04*. (Of course you need Wi-Fi dongle for pi2)

Good Luck!