# How to setup of Raspberry Pi 3 onboard WiFi for Ubuntu Server with 'netplan'?

Tags: server, wireless, 18.04, raspberrypi, netplan

How to setup of Raspberry Pi 3 B+ onboard WiFi for Ubuntu Server 18.04? In particular, with `netplan`?

Existing answers, such as ["How to use onboard wifi on Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu Server 16.04?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775597/how-to-use-onboard-wifi-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-ubuntu-server-16-04), no longer seem to apply since `/etc/network/interfaces` states that `netplan` has replaced `ifupdown`.

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
```

This is a clean install of the [Ubuntu Server image for Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3).

```
##### release ###########################
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################
Linux 4.15.0-1034-raspi2 #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 5 06:21:41 UTC 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

According to [Ubuntu Wiki RaspberryPI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#WiFi) the needed packages should already be in place.

> Since 18.04.2 the linux-firmware and linux-firmware-raspi2 packages now contain the necessary files for the built-in WiFi on the Pi 3B and 3B+.

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network:0 DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: b8:27:eb:69:f2:3b
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.18 firmware=01-6a2c8ad4 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: eth0
   serial: b8:27:eb:3c:a7:6e
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=lan78xx driverversion=1.0.6 duplex=full ip=172.16.76.7 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

Netplan.io provides some general [Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples).

> To configure netplan, save configuration files under `/etc/netplan/` with a `.yaml` extension (e.g. `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`), then run `sudo netplan apply`.

... yet, no guideance specific to a RaspberryPi. ...in particular, with respect to the *existing /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml* file on the RaspberryPi Ubuntu Server install.

```
##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml]

# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}

network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
            set-name: eth0
```

So, given the use of `netplan` and default *generated `.yaml`* file. How should one *add* a WiFi network SSID and password? And leave the existing wired ethernet in place?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi 3 B+ has some weird quirks with the Wireless/Bluetooth chipset.  You may have better luck on a [Raspberry Pi-specific](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) exchange.

Comment: @Nmath The installed image is `ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` specifically for raspi3 ... provided the ubuntu.com download is correct. Ubuntu information indicates that "linux-firmware-raspi2 packages now contain the necessary files for the built-in WiFi on the Pi 3B and 3B+". As such, information so far seems to indicates that the `uname --kernel-version` result of `4.15.0-1034-raspi2` is OK. ... and, hopefully, the current next step is more about using `netplan` on an Ubuntu RaspPi install.

Comment: @earthmeLon Usually I don't cross post questions. It seemed that this issue is more Ubuntu centric with Ubuntu 18.04 switch to `netplan`. That said, after contemplating your suggestion, I did end up posting a Raspberry Pi variant of the ["How to setup the Raspberry Pi 3 onboard WiFi for Ubuntu Server 18.04 with netplan?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98598) question on the Raspberry Pi exchange.

Comment: I'm not asking you to cross post.  Just providing some details.  No need to defend your choice to post here.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The steps below were found to provide a persistent WiFi setup using `netplan` with Ubuntu Server 18.04 `ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` image on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Update system:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Determine interface names:

```bash
ip link show

# 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> …
# 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> … state UP …
# 3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> … state DOWN
```

Determine your-cloud-init.yaml and open for editing.

```bash
cd /etc/netplan/
ls -l
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 666 May 15 22:00 50-cloud-init.yaml
### note your *cloud-init.yaml file name

### backup *cloud-init.yaml file
cp 50-cloud-init.yaml 50-cloud-init.yaml.bak
### restrict read access
sudo chmod 640 /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
### edit *cloud-init.yaml
sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Add WiFi access information to your-cloud-init.yaml file.

```yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            optional: true
            dhcp4: true
    # add wifi setup information here ...
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "YOUR-SSID-NAME":
                    password: "YOUR-NETWORK-PASSWORD"
            dhcp4: true
```

Test, generate and apply the changed your-cloud-init.yaml config:

- Testing: `sudo netplan --debug try` (continue even if successful)
- Generate: `sudo netplan --debug generate` (provides more details in case of issues with the previous command)
- Apply: `sudo netplan --debug apply` (if no issues during the previous commands)

Confirmation Test:

```bash
sudo reboot

### wait, then without the wired ethernet connected ... 
ssh ubuntu@wifi-ip-address
```

*The above sequence was distilled from the "[Raspberry Pi 3B/B+ Wireless Bridge using Ubuntu Server 18.04 ARM Image and Netplan](https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564)" gist link mentioned by [Larnu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/103117/larnu).  The gist goes well beyond just enabling WiFi since its turns the Pi into a Bridge.*

---

Some additional useful WiFi setup steps.

*Set hostname.*

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname my-server-name
```

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

```bash
127.0.0.1 localhost
# add host name
127.0.0.1 my-server-name
```

`sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

```ini
# Set preserve_hostname to true for persistance after reboot
preserve_hostname: true
```

Verify from local Raspberry Pi commandline.

```bash
hostnamectl
#   Static hostname: my-server-name
#         Icon name: computer
#        Machine ID: …
#           Boot ID: …
#  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
#            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-1036-raspi2
#      Architecture: arm64
```

*Enable mDNS.*

If desired, enable [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) by installing [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)). Avahi supports the mDNS/DNS-SD/RFC 3927/Zeroconf/Bonjour specification.

```bash
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Remotely check mDNS resolution from another computer.

```bash
ping my-server-name.local
ssh ubuntu@my-server-name.local
```

Comment: When you add the wifi password for a first boot configuration does the config file that contains the password remain or is it removed after it has been read and configured?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1874377

Currently Ubuntu 20.04.1 needs reboot even though the issue is supposed to be fixed. Cable internet connects immediately.
Ubuntu 20.10 connects to wifi even without reboot for now.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers in the current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS lack the clm_blob if you have a Broadcom 43430 Wifi chipset. I lost the WiFi in an update. The only way to solve this problem was to switch to Alpine and install the firmware-cypress APK. I hope Ubuntu fixes this soon!