# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - How to connect Wi-Fi on Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+

Tags: server, wireless, 20.04, raspberrypi, netplan

Can't get the Wi-Fi work on Ubuntu Server 20.04.1, installed to Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+.
All ways that I use before and googled now, not work.

First, I tried method that worked in 18.04 and 19.10:

```
sudo su
rm /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
cp /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml /etc/netplan/wireless.yaml
nano /etc/netplan/wireless.yaml

network
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 wifis:
   wlan0:
     dhcp4: yes
     access-points:
       "MY_WF":
         password: "12345678"

netplan apply
shutdown -r now
```

After that I googled and find this:

```
network
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "MY_WF":
                    password: "12345678"
            dhcp4: true

netplan apply
shutdown -r now
```

But still no luck :(
Also I tried make file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with network: {config: disabled}

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /etc/netplan`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
same issue (but with raspberry PI 3 model B)

solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/1143594/385361 works for me… (with my right wifi password). Finally, I just add lines in */etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml* and reboot.

If it doesn't works, think to have a look to your */var/log/syslog* and search *netplan* or/and *wlan0* words, in my case with bad password, I had :

```
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="my_ssid_box" auth_failures=1
```

Comment: What is the relevant difference between what OP did and what is done in the linked answer? As far as I understand it in both cases `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` is edited (ok and OP basically renamed it but that doesn't seem relevant) to include the `wifis: wlan0: ...` part and they look exactly the same to me.

Comment: you're right, nothing really relevant, excepted perhaps the syslog information to check ?