# How to connect Ubuntu server to the internet (Raspberry Pi 3B+)

Tags: server, network-manager, internet

After a good 4 hours of repeatedly following tutorials that involve [netplan](https://djanotes.blogspot.com/2018/03/connecting-to-wifi-network-with-netplan.html), or [some other form of connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775597/how-to-use-onboard-wifi-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-ubuntu-server-16-04) I'm here to ask how to connect my Raspberry Pi 3B+ to the internet. To clarify, here's what I DON'T have access to.

- Ethernet connection
- NetworkManager System Program (the reason NetPlan won't work :/)
- Access to the `iwconfig` command

Remember, this is on a Raspberry Pi image downloaded and flashed from Ubuntu's website. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What release/version of Ubuntu are you asking about?

Comment: @guiverc 18.04 Raspberry Pi 3B+ Server